# Passing arguments from one class to another class using threading python

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading

I'm new to threading and python. I would like to understand how to pass multiple arguments from one class to another class in python using threading.

I'm using a main thread to call a class- Process then inside the run I'm doing some business logic and calling another class- build using thread and passing multiple arguments.

The run of build class is getting executed but Inside the build class, I'm unable to access those arguments and hence not able to proceed further.

Not sure if my approach is right? Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Below is my main class :

```
from threading import Thread
import logging as log
from process import Process

         
if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        proc = Process()
        proc.start()
    
    except Exception as e:
        #log some error
```

Inside Process:

#all the dependencies are imported

```
class Process(Thread):
    '''
    classdocs
    '''

    def __init__(self):
        '''
        Constructor
        '''
        Thread.__init__(self)
        #other intializations

    def run(self):
        #some other logic
        self.notification(pass_some_data)



   #inside notification I'm calling another thread
   def notification(self,passed_data):
       #passed data is converted dict1
       #tup1 is being formed from another function.
       #build is a class, and if i don't pass None, i get groupname error.
       th = build(None,(tup1,),(dict1,))
       th.start()
```

#inside build

```
class build(Thread):
   
    def _init_(self,tup1,dict1):
    
        super(build,self).__init__(self)
        self.tup1 = tup1
        self.dict1 = dict1

    def run(self):
       #some business logic
       #I'm unable to get the arguments being passed here.
```

Comment: The arguments what I'm passing are tuple and a dictionary

Comment: `th = build(tup1, dict1)`